# using angular-dynamic locale webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-i18n

How to use the angular-dynamic-locale with webpack?

The angular-dynamic-locale always tries to load the angular-locale_en.js file from path http://localhost:8080/angular/i18n/angular-locale_de.js during the running-time, when the "tmhDynamicLocale.set('de');" is performed.

I'm using webpack therefore I define every dependencies either in the top of my app.js or in the top of my controllers. I tried to define this with require('angular-i18n/angular-locale_de') or with import, but unfortunatelly, I always get the following error messages:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/angular/i18n/angular-locale_de.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8080/angular/i18n/angular-locale_de.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Comment: have you tried CopyWebpackPlugin ? to copy the locales to the destination folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your locales like this:

```
tmhDynamicLocaleProvider
    .localeLocationPattern('./angular/i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js')
    .defaultLocale('de');
```

You can probably use CopyWebpackPlugin like this:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {from: './node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_de.js', to: path.resolve(__dirname, '.[WEBPACK OUTPUT FOLDER]' + '/angular/i18n')}
])
```

Be sure that the destination folder matches the output of your webpacked files

Comment: what to do in case of dynamic locale based on condition? i want to add two locale file one for  de and another for en